# Should I dequeue cell instead allocate it, if cell is UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

What is a better way:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    return cell
}
```

or

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier) //cell has empty prototype in storyboard where setted this cellIdentifier
    return cell
}
```

I know dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier will reuse cells. But it would be better for performance in this case if we use simple UITableViewCell?

Comment: What do you mean by `in this case`? Which case? Is this going to be dynamic or static content table view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never use the first method. Performance wise the dequeuing method is much much better.

If you want a cell with a different style or different labels then create that in the storyboard or create a subclass.

But always use the dequeuing method.

Comment: But I do not want any different style or different labels. It should be simple UITableViewCell, so even don't need any prototype at all. What benefits I get from dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier in this case?

Comment: @TarasChernyshenko using the dequeue method will only create enough cells for number of rows on screen at any time. For any additional rows these, already created, cells are reused. They no longer have to be created and configured. The only thing that needs to happen is for you to set the text on labels etc...

Comment: With your first method then it will also (I think, I hope) only create enough cells for the rows on screen but then when you scroll it will create new cells for every single row that comes into view. Even scrolling back to the top will create new cells. So now you have the overhead of having to create the views and all the subviews and constraints every time. Instead of just setting the text etc...

Answer (score 0):

Both are absolutely fine. It depends on you what type of setting you want. As far as dequeueReusableCell is consider it just save the memory. It allocates only some number of cell which can easily be shown into you device screen. For example if your screen can view 7 cells it will allocate 8 cells and then try to reuse these cell for different number of objects with respect to their indexPath.